# Is there a easy way to run yugabyte db in local (mac os) with python3?

Tags: yugabytedb

I'm setting up Yugabyte (YB) locally on my work computer without admin rights or Docker installation. Python 3.x runs with the command 'python3,' and creating an alias to 'python' didn't work for YB. To make it work, I created a symbolic link in the home folder. Is there a way to start Yugabyte without needing to create this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yugabyted` runs `python`: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/master/bin/yugabyted#L1
I think you can simply call `python3 $YB_HOME/bin/yugabyted`